# Zoom installed, and still I have to download and start a tiny zoom.exe to join a meeting

Tags: installation, download, hyperlink, file-download, zoom-meeting

Zoom is installed:

[image]

Still, I always need to click on `Don't have Zoom Client installed? /Download now/'` and download a tiny zoom exe file (e.g. 82 KB `Zoom_cm_fof5Mnoeekuws8Z9vvrZo4_mdzzwr9AzI9fg9k2dQxDcz-EI4z3mzKEW1ryR@3M1wBFrsXm8isE..._.exe`) and double-click that to join a meeting.

[image]

[image]

I would normally just join a meeting directly when clicking on a zoom link, how can I avoid the extra step, without using the second option `Join from Your Browser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by re-opening the page in a new browser window (I even used private mode, not sure whether that is needed) and then of course by re-clicking the Zoom link again. Then I did not need to download the tiny .exe file. Not sure if a new instance is needed at all, please test whether a new tab is already enough. Please also test whether the private mode is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download the zoom.exe everytime, instead, just click the "Launch Meeting" button and that will take you directly to the meeting. :)

Comment: Launch is "start" for me and I remember having started a meeting with that button a couple of times without joining one - I became the host, then, no one in the channel. In my opinion, the button would have to be called `Join Meeting`. That is why I avoided the button. The answer might be really obvious to everyone, but not for me ;). I have English as a second language and I never use "launch" in everyday life, my fault.

Comment: In your picture there is a button that says "Launch Meeting", if you press that, it will take you to the meeting you want to join.

Comment: I have seen that, of course. It is just a language thing here. I do not expect a "Lanuch Meeting", but a "Join Meeting". Anyway, that is solved :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: I normally use Linux, but once when I had to use Zoom on a Windows computer, despite having Zoom installed, the "Launch Meeting" option didn't work for me - it started Zoom without the meeting data, so I had to manually enter the meeting ID and password. The only way to join meeting automatically was to download that .exe file OP mentions. On Linux it works OK.

Comment: @raj I will check that at the next meeting. I also remember the same as you, that is why I have not tried the "Launch Meeting" button anymore since months. If it does not work, the answer is wrong, we will see. Perhaps it is just a Firefox issue? I will also check it in Edge then.

Comment: The answer is wrong, I have undone the "accept". I have tested it on a computer in my own language, and "Launch meeting" is to - directly translated - "open" a new meeting, not to join it. What was also needed was to wait a little time for the Zoom link to be executed, no need to download it. And since I used the same settings (I have synced my Firefox by signing up an account), Firefox settings cannot be the reason for this problem either.

Comment: Its different on my computer. :)

Comment: I must admit that I have not checked your solution before dropping the other answer because I thought that launching cannot be right in any case, the word itself does not fit. As soon as I have this problem again, I will click on "launch meeting" to see whether you are right. Or someone else should test it and comment.

Comment: I have checked this when I did not have to download a small exe and I had nothing but the "Launch Meeting button" button, and it worked by just clicking on it as the other answer had said before. But that does not answer the question, since that is about the problem of having to download a small exe file, and in that case, launching might probably not help. I have not had the issue again to test.